# Sequelize - How return rows only if included model has at least one record

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to this query in Sequelize:

```
const results = await WorkflowAssignation.findAndCountAll(
                        {
                            limit: limit, 
                            offset: offset, 
                            where: 
                                { 
                                    userId: userIds, 
                                    status: status
                                }, 
                            include: [ 
                                { 
                                    model: WorkflowStepAssignation,
                                    include: [ 
                                        { model: WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser, include: [ users ]}
                                    ] 
                                }, 
                                { model: users } 
                            ], 
                            distinct: true, 
                            order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC'], [ { model: WorkflowStepAssignation, as: "steps" }, 'stepNumber', 'ASC' ] ]  
                        });
```

The problem is that I need to return only `WorkflowAssignation` if the `WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser` table contain at least 1 record with the value passed as parameter for `userid`.

if I used a `where` in this line `{ model: WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser, include: [ users ]}` it will still return all the `WorkflowAssignation` with only the steps that has the `userId` value and that's not what I want.

It is like I want to return all the `WorkflowAssignation` including all the tables but only if in `WorkflowStepAssignation -> WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser` has the users in the parameters.

Relations are:

`WorkflowAssignation`

has Many

`WorkflowStepAssignation`

has Many

`WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser` (has a `userId` column)

Answer (score 0):

add `required: true`

```
const results = await WorkflowAssignation.findAndCountAll(
                    {
                        limit: limit, 
                        offset: offset, 
                        where: 
                            { 
                                userId: userIds, 
                                status: status
                            }, 
                        include: [ 
                            { 
                                model: WorkflowStepAssignation,
                                include: [ 
                                    { model: WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser, include: [ users ]}
                                ] 
                            }, 
                            { model: users } 
                        ], 
                        distinct: true, 
                        required: true,
                        order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC'], [ { model: 
                        WorkflowStepAssignation, as: "steps" }, 'stepNumber', 'ASC' ] ]  
                    });
```